# Search Funtion in An Array React.js

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of universities
And I need to make a search funtion.
My search implementation works perfectly and finds the university that I type.
However when I select the option, it confuses itself and always select by new index.

For example my array is ["A.T. Still University", "Abilene Christian University", "Abraham Baldwin University", "Academy for Five Element University" ... ]

In here, A.T. Still University is at the 0 index originally. and when I make a search with filter, it creates a new array. I type "Abilene" for example and it brings me a new array with results and "Abilene" becomes at the 0 index. However it doesnt select this one and keeps selecting "A.T. Still University" which has the original 0 index.

Can someone help me how to fix this problem ?
I want to be able to select what I type in search area.
My code is below

```
const SignupStep5 = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userInfo = useSelector(state => state.profile.user);
  const universityList = useSelector(state => state.config.universities);
  const isFetchingUniversity = useSelector(state =>
    isLoadingSelector([fetchUniversities], state),
  );

  //State
  const [
    selectedUniversityId,
    setSelectedUniversityId,
    selectedUniversityIdRef,
  ] = useStateRef(null);
  const [choosenUniversity, setChoosenUniversity, choosenUniversityRef] =
    useStateRef('');
  const [choosenUniversityId, setChoosenUniversityId, choosenUniversityIdRef] =
    useStateRef('');


  useEffect(() => {
    if (universityList.length) {
      if (props.activeIndex == 5 && userInfo && userInfo.university) {
        const index = universityList.findIndex(university =>
          isEqual(university, userInfo.university),
        );

        if (index !== -1) {
          setSelectedUniversityId(index);
          setChoosenUniversity(userInfo.university);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [universityList]);



  const renderHeader = () => (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.modalHeaderContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.modalHeaderText}>
          {strings.aboutMe.selectUniversity}
        </Text>
        <Touchable
          style={styles.modalHeaderTextContainer}
          onPress={() => {
            if (selectedUniversityIdRef.current != null) {
              setChoosenUniversityId(selectedUniversityIdRef.current);
              setChoosenUniversity(
                universityList[selectedUniversityIdRef.current],
              );
              closeBottomSheet();
            }
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.modalHeaderSelectText}>
            {strings.common.select}
          </Text>
        </Touchable>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.modalHeaderLine}></View>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
    <Touchable
      style={
        selectedUniversityIdRef.current === index
          ? styles.modalChildContainerSelected
          : styles.modalChildContainer
      }
      onPress={() => handleSelection(index)}>
      <Text style={styles.modalChildText}>{item}</Text>
    </Touchable>
  );


  const handleSelection = id => {
    const selectedId = selectedUniversityIdRef.current;
    if (selectedId === id) setSelectedUniversityId(null);
    else setSelectedUniversityId(id);
  };

  const onOverlayPress = () => {
    if (choosenUniversityRef.current) {
      const index = universityList.findIndex(
        university => university === choosenUniversityRef.current,
      );
      if (index !== -1) {
        setSelectedUniversityId(index);
      }
    } else if (
      selectedUniversityIdRef.current != null &&
      !choosenUniversityRef.current
    ) {
      setSelectedUniversityId(null);
    }
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');
  const searchInputFields = () => {
     const filteredUniversity = universityList.filter(value => {
       return value.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
   });
    return filteredUniversity;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Portal>
        {props.activeIndex == 5 && (
          <BottomSheet
            ref={bottomSheetRef}
            snapPoints={snapPoints}
            handleComponent={renderHeader}
            backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
            onAnimate={handleSheetChanges}>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={value => setSearchField(value)}
              value={searchField}
              style={{padding: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}}
              placeholder="Search"
              placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
            />
            <BottomSheetFlatList
              data={searchField ? searchInputFields() : universityList}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.modalChildStyle}
              extraData={selectedUniversityIdRef.current}
            />
          </BottomSheet>
        )}
      </Portal>
    </>
  );
});

export default SignupStep5;
```

Comment: This looks like React Native, no? Please show how you're initializing and setting `selectedUniversityIdRef`. Component headers are nice too so we can see your props (or lack thereof).

Comment: yes it is react native. I changed the code and implemented the whole code for this cmponent. @ggorlen

Comment: Thanks but that's too much noise now. We need a [mcve]--the bare minimum to reproduce the problem, nothing more or less. (Yes, it takes work to produce a simple, runnable MCVE--that's the debugging process)

Comment: ok, so I removed unnecessary parts. the codes were written by another developer and I am trying to make a search funtion on it so i couldnt find where the mistake about the indexes @ggorlen